# iPhone UIImageView, CABasicAnimation rotation with fixed background

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, rotation

I have an `UIImageView` which I can rotate using `CABasicAnimation`. That works fine. Now I wanted to add a fixed background view, which should stay unchanged and shall not follow the rotation (think of a radar device with fixed target echos).

I have added my bg as subview to the `UIImageView`, but unfortunately (but not unexpectedly) the whole image rotates, not only the foreground, if I rotate the layer of my `UIImageView`.

Is there a way to have a fixed background layer and a rotating layer on top? Even if I add my background as layer to the `UIImageView` layer the whole thing rotates...

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rearrange your layout so that you have a superview that contains both your background and the UIImageView that needs rotating—something like this:

- Container View

  - Background View
  - UIImageView

That way, you can rotate the UIImageView at will without affecting the background.

Of course, the container view is only useful if you eventually need to manipulate both the background and the image view together, at which point you can simply animate the container, thus affecting both.

Comment: OK, what I did now is to add both images as new sublayers to the UIImageView. I do that once. Finally I rotate one of the layers only.

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate parent view then all subview will also rotate. For this you don't need to make background and foreground subview of one another. Add the background to a parent view, then add foreground to the same parent view, that is foreground is not child of background. Then apply rotation only on the foreground (not on the parent view). This should not affect the background or other child of the parent.